# Do I need to change source code of my website every time I want to update contents?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, blogs

I have made a blog post website using html, css and JavaScript. But, every time I want to update or post a new post, its need to change the main source code to do that. Is there any way to update/post on exact placeholder of my website without changing any source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the backend, you can create a database that stores the data for posts. Then, whenever you need to create a post, have an interface on the front-end that allows you to add/modify the data in database.

When web requests are made to the blog, look up the database and render the posts that are in it.

These are the bare-bones of what's commonly known as a "[content management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)". Once the code is all set up, there shouldn't be any need for further coding to add, edit, and remove content.

Comment: Could you tell me, what knowledge/tools should I know to do that? My programming knowledge is mostly based on JavaScript and Python.

Comment: @Sobhani You might check out Node.js.  There are plenty of JavaScript-based template engines.  Some simple JavaScript is all that's needed to inject dynamic data into the template, and output some HTML that then becomes effectively static. You can also render the pages on-the-fly if you want.

Comment: @Sobhani I'm not sure on Python, but if you know JS, the essentials would be relatively simple to set up using Node (use Express for a web server), PostgreSQL (or whatever DB you prefer), and EJS for rendering. That's just one option that I'm familiar with, there are lots and lots of ways to do it.